# Multiprocessing basic example running in sequential order rather than parallel in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

Question: Use multiprocessing to create three separate processes. Make each one wait a random number of seconds between one and five, print the current time, and then exit.

```
# 6) Use multiprocessing to create three separate processes. Make each one wait a random number 
# of seconds between one and five, print the current time, and then exit. 
import multiprocessing,time,datetime
import zoo 

# def process1():
#     t1 = random.randint(1,5)
#     print("Waiting for "+str(t1)+" seconds")
#     time.sleep(t1)
#     print(datetime.datetime.now())


start = time.time()
process1 = zoo.process1()
process2 = zoo.process1()
process3 = zoo.process1()

print(datetime.datetime.now())
if __name__=="__main__":
    
    
    
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process2)
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process3)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()

end = time.time()
    

print("It takes " +str(end-start)+" seconds")
```

Comment: Your code should work. I tested it in both modern Jupyter notebook and JupyterLab. Click [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/master?filepath=index.ipynbr) to try in Jupyter notebook yourself; click [here](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/master) to try in JupyterLab yourself. Your code is also set up to be run as a script. To test if that helps, paste that into a text file, save it as `myscript.py`, and run it from your notebook with `%run myscript.py`.

Comment: You have to import `process1` from an external module if you are going to run it in Jupyter Notebook. At least that has always been the case.

Comment: I have done as you asked - Still facing an issue - could you please help? 

@Booboo